# Google Apps Script - convert UrlFetch response to array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using UrlFetch to get data from a Googe script:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); 
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(typeof(response))
```

This is logging:

```
[["Name","email","2016-12-31T00:00:00.000Z","Sim",548]]
object
```

The response looks like an array but it is an object. I need to be able to loop through an array, so how do I convert this data to an array instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what type of content returned by the query. Suppose, for example, it JSON:

```
    function myFunction() {

        var url = "http://headers.jsontest.com/";
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); 

        Logger.log(response.getContentText());

        try {
            // Regular expression for JSON content-type
            var jsr = new RegExp(/application\/json/);
            var cnt = response.getAllHeaders()["Content-Type"];

            // Check if response is JSON
            if (jsr.exec(cnt)) {
                // Parse response content
                var js =  JSON.parse( response.getContentText() );
                Logger.log(js);
                for (var i in js) {
                  var t = {}; t[i] = js[i];
                  Logger.log( t );
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {
           Logger.log(e)
        }

   }
```